# Issue with saving to Parse through Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, parse-platform, save

I have the following code which works fine:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
Parse.initialize("Lvw6b7TPacv0DX949odBhUPo2nqH5az7SPg6qoiD", "PIuBiR1tGtdJ8IDMnX3yEiljW4V3FQjeoEOhmzEW");

var Recipe = Parse.object.extend("UserSignUp");
var recipe = new Recipe();
  recipe.save({username: "<?php echo $Username  ?>",password: "<?php echo $Password  ?>",title: "<?php echo $Title ?>",name: "<?php echo $Name ?>",email: "<?php echo $Email ?>",summary: "<?php echo $Summary ?>"}, {
  success: function(object) {
    $(".success").show();
  },
  error: function(model, error) {
    $(".error").show();
  }
});
```

However this saves to a usersignup class which I created. Ideally I need the data to be saved the User installation class however I am unable to do so.

How can this be achieved??

Answer (score 1):

For sure, the code creates a UserSignUp (confusingly named Recipe) and saves it.  The create method for Parse.User is called `signUp()`.

copied from [the doc:](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-signup)

```
var user = new Parse.User();
user.set("username", "my name");
user.set("password", "my pass");
user.set("email", "email@example.com");

// other fields can be set just like with Parse.Object
user.set("phone", "415-392-0202");

user.signUp(null, {
  success: function(user) {
    // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
  },
  error: function(user, error) {
    // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: We have changed that around however we are getting an error:



error100XMLHttpRequest failed: {"readyState":4,"timeout":0,"onloadend":null,"withCredentials":false,"onloadstart":null,"status":0,"ontimeout":null,"onabort":null,"upload":{"onabort":null,"onload":null,"onprogress":null,"onerror":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null},"responseType":"","response":"","responseXML":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"statusText":"","onprogress":null,"responseText":""}